# Multiple FK in Relationship Table, Returning Rows in one Result but joining on different column as FK

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a Relationship Table, where there are 4 FK back to a User Table...that "tags" certain Users who did certain things on an Entity.

I've fabricated a made-up-example below.  I would not solve a "relationship of people" problem as below.  But this is a made up example to show what I have in my existing database.

The issue is that I bring back info from the Person table ... but based on the FK in the relationship table.....defines how the (other) Person is related to me.  (Again, this is a made up example)

Right now, my existing query "flattens out" the data, with alot of LEFT joins.  Aka, where I have 4 columns of data per person, my existing query has 20 columns (4 columns x 5 person-types)....with alias column names.  "MotherLastName, MotherFirstName, MotherCreateDate" etc etc.

Is there a way to bring back all 5 rows, in one result, outside of the UNION ALL I've done below.

There may not be, but I'm a C# developer, not a TSQL super-guru.

I'm also ok with bringing back 5 results (first attempt) if that is most efficient.  But I don't think that is the case.

Anyway...Just some Friday think-tanking.

Thanks for any hints.

```
-- START TSQL

SET NOCOUNT ON


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] 
END 
GO


IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[Person]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN 
DROP TABLE [dbo].[Person] 
END 






CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Person] ( 

    [PersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [varchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    )

GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.Person ADD CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (PersonUUID) 
GO




IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.sysobjects WHERE id = object_id(N'[dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople]') and OBJECTPROPERTY(id, N'IsUserTable') = 1) 
BEGIN DROP TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] 
END 
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] ( 
      [PersonSpecialPeopleSurrogateUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    , [CreateDate] [datetime] NOT NULL
    , [MePersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    , [BestFriendPersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    , [SpousePersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    , [FatherPersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL
    , [MotherPersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL

)


GO

ALTER TABLE dbo.PersonSpecialPeople ADD CONSTRAINT PK_PersonSpecialPeople PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED (PersonSpecialPeopleSurrogateUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESP_MePersonUUID_To_PersonUUID FOREIGN KEY ([MePersonUUID]) REFERENCES dbo.Person (PersonUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESP_BestFriendPersonUUID_To_PersonUUID FOREIGN KEY (BestFriendPersonUUID) REFERENCES dbo.Person (PersonUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESP_SpousePersonUUID_To_PersonUUID FOREIGN KEY ([SpousePersonUUID]) REFERENCES dbo.Person (PersonUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESP_FatherPersonUUID_To_PersonUUID FOREIGN KEY ([FatherPersonUUID]) REFERENCES dbo.Person (PersonUUID) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] ADD CONSTRAINT FK_ESP_MotherPersonUUID_To_PersonUUID FOREIGN KEY ([MotherPersonUUID]) REFERENCES dbo.Person (PersonUUID) 
GO


declare @PersonUUID_Me [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_Me = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111'

declare @PersonUUID_BestFriend [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_BestFriend = '44444444-4444-4444-4444-444444444444'
declare @PersonUUID_Spouse [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_Spouse = '55555555-5555-5555-5555-555555555555'
declare @PersonUUID_Father [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_Father = '77777777-7777-7777-7777-777777777777'
declare @PersonUUID_Mother [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_Mother = '88888888-8888-8888-8888-888888888888'

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Person] (    [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , [CreateDate] )
    Select @PersonUUID_Me , 'Coder', 'Granada' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    UNION ALL Select @PersonUUID_BestFriend , 'Stephenson', 'Leo' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    UNION ALL Select @PersonUUID_Spouse , 'Matheas', 'Mandie' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    UNION ALL Select @PersonUUID_Father , 'Coder', 'Daddy' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    UNION ALL Select @PersonUUID_Mother , 'Coder', 'Mommy' , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

INSERT INTO [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] ( 
      [PersonSpecialPeopleSurrogateUUID] 
    , [CreateDate] 
    , [MePersonUUID]
    , [BestFriendPersonUUID] 
    , [SpousePersonUUID] 
    , [FatherPersonUUID] 
    , [MotherPersonUUID] )
Select NEWID() , CURRENT_TIMESTAMP , @PersonUUID_Me , @PersonUUID_BestFriend , @PersonUUID_Spouse , @PersonUUID_Father , @PersonUUID_Mother 



/* Version One, Get 1 Result per Person "Type" */

Select  [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , [CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    where per.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me

Select  [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = BestFriendPersonUUID 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me

Select  [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = [SpousePersonUUID] 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me

Select  [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = [FatherPersonUUID] 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me

Select  [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = [MotherPersonUUID] 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me



/* Version Two, Get 1 Result , with Union-All, with a unique 'Tag' as first column */

Select  [Relationship] = 'Me' , [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , [CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    where per.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me
UNION ALL
Select  [Relationship] = 'BestFriend' ,     [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = BestFriendPersonUUID 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me
UNION ALL
Select  [Relationship] = 'Spouse' ,     [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = [SpousePersonUUID] 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me
UNION ALL
Select  [Relationship] = 'Father' ,     [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = [FatherPersonUUID] 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me
UNION ALL
Select  [Relationship] = 'Mother' ,     [PersonUUID] , [LastName] , [FirstName] , per.[CreateDate] from [dbo].[Person] per
    join [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec on per.PersonUUID = [MotherPersonUUID] 
    where spec.[MePersonUUID] = @PersonUUID_Me
```

Comment: What is wrong with the `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Nothing really.  Like I said, it's a think-tank question.  I didn't know if there is some fancy-smanchy JOIN syntax.  I'm "for" the UNION-ALL Solution...it is my idea to rework this query here on the job site.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid the `UNION`, you can use a `JOIN` and `CASE` construct like this:

First create a relationship table:

```
CREATE TABLE [rel] ([Relationship] varchar(20) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO [rel] VALUES('BestFriend'),('Spouse'),('Father'),('Mother');
```

Then you can execute the following statement:

```
SELECT [rel].[Relationship], per.[PersonUUID], per.[LastName], per.[FirstName], per.[CreateDate]
  FROM [dbo].[Person] per
       CROSS JOIN [rel]
       JOIN [dbo].[PersonSpecialPeople] spec ON
            per.PersonUUID = 
            CASE [rel].[Relationship]
                 WHEN 'BestFriend' THEN  BestFriendPersonUUID
                 WHEN 'Spouse' THEN  SpousePersonUUID
                 WHEN 'Father' THEN  FatherPersonUUID
                 WHEN 'Mother' THEN  MotherPersonUUID
            END
```

This uses the fact that that joins need not be use a simple `a.colA = b.colB` condition, but you can state anything that results in a Boolean value in the condition. However, most database optimizers are more tuned towards joins of the standard form `a.colA = b.colB`.

Answer (score 1):

OPTION 1: 
Check out using UNPIVOT (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx).  Here is an example, which only uses one UNION ALL to get the base person and then all relationships:

```
declare @PersonUUID_Me [uniqueidentifier]
select @PersonUUID_Me = '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111';


SELECT Relationship = 'Me', p.PersonUUID, p.LastName, p.FirstName, p.CreateDate
FROM dbo.Person p
WHERE p.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me

UNION ALL 

SELECT Relationship = replace(unpvt.ReleationshipType, 'PersonUUID', ''), unpvt.RelPersonUUID, p.LastName, p.FirstName, unpvt.CreateDate
FROM 
(
    SELECT *
    FROM dbo.PersonSpecialPeople
    where MePersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me
) sp
UNPIVOT (RelPersonUUID FOR ReleationshipType IN 
    ([BestFriendPersonUUID] 
    , [SpousePersonUUID] 
    , [FatherPersonUUID] 
    , [MotherPersonUUID] 
    ) 
) as unpvt
INNER JOIN dbo.Person p ON p.PersonUUID = unpvt.RelPersonUUID
```

OPTION 2: 
You also could reconsider normalizing the database structure to have the following new tables: RelationshipType, PersonRelationship, and get rid of [PersonSpecialPeople].  If this is an existing application that I understand this is tough to do.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.RelationshipType(RelationshipTypeID int not null primary key identity, Relationship nvarchar(50) not null)
go

CREATE TABLE dbo.PersonRelationship(
    [PersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL foreign key references dbo.Person(PersonUUID), 
    [RelPersonUUID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL foreign key references dbo.Person(PersonUUID),
    RelationshipTypeID int not null foreign key references dbo.RelationshipType(RelationshipTypeID),
    CreateDate datetime not null
)
go
```

Then to populate new tables:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.RelationshipType(Relationship)
VALUES('BestFriend')
,('Spouse')
,('Father')
,('Mother')
;

INSERT INTO dbo.PersonRelationship(PersonUUID, RelPersonUUID, RelationshipTypeID, CreateDate)
VALUES(@PersonUUID_Me, @PersonUUID_BestFriend,1, current_timestamp)
,(@PersonUUID_Me, @PersonUUID_Spouse, 2, current_timestamp)
,(@PersonUUID_Me, @PersonUUID_Father,3, current_timestamp)
,(@PersonUUID_Me, @PersonUUID_Mother,4, current_timestamp)
```

And finally the simplified select statement, which *does not need to be modified in a new RelationshipType is added*.  NOTE: don't use select * in your actual production code, list each of the columns out individually.

```
SELECT Relationship = cast('Me' as varchar(50)), p.* 
FROM dbo.Person p
where p.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me

union all

select rt.Relationship, p.* 
from dbo.PersonRelationship r
inner join dbo.Person p on p.PersonUUID = r.RelPersonUUID
inner join dbo.RelationshipType rt on rt.RelationshipTypeID = r.RelationshipTypeID
where r.PersonUUID = @PersonUUID_Me
```

Comment: If I designed the db, it would have been OPTION 2.  Thanks for the other option.